# Обрезка изображения OpenCV в Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

Нужно реализовать функцию, которая будет обрезать изображение требуемой ширины и высоты. Для входных аргументов в функции random_crop(img, width=None, height=None, seed=1) используются img - исходное изображение, width, height - ширина, высота, а так же параметр seed, который используется для задания np.random.seed() при генерации координат левого верхнего угла обрезки.

Похожих задач не нашел (или возможно не понял), не понимаю как задать координаты top_y, bottom_y, right_x, left_x используя np.random.randint() чтоб получить что то вроде crop = img[top_y:bottom_y, right_x:left_x].

Сначала я пробовал решить таким образом:

```
def random_crop(img, width=None, height=None, seed=1):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    top_y = np.random.randint(height)
    bottom_y = top_y + height
    rand_w = np.random.randint(width)
    top_x = width + (rand_w*2)
    bottom_x = (width*2) + rand_w
    crop = img[top_y:bottom_y,top_x:bottom_x]
    return crop
```

Результат для моей задачи подходил, но вот в следующих задачах функция не работала как надо, что и понятно.

Затем пробовал в самом изображении как то перетасовать координаты:

```
def random_crop(img, width=None, height=None, seed=1):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    x = np.random.randint(img_cv[1][0][1])
    y = np.random.randint(img_cv[0][0][1])
    crop = img[y:height+y, width+x:width+width+x]
    return crop
```

Результат так же похож, но все еще очень мутно.

Мне кажется для этого все должно быть проще, а я очень далек от этого.

Есть догадки использовать .shape для генерации точек x и y:

```
y = np.random.randint(img.shape[0])
x = np.random.randint(img.shape[1])
```

но тут я опять запнулся. Может кто нибудь понял в чем суть задачи и сможет мне помочь.

Допустим есть картинка в виде массива NumPy, shape которого (194, 260, 3). Нужно сгенерировать точки x и y (левая верхняя точка), начиная с которых будет вырезаться картинка (конечные точки будут x+width и y+height). При этом, в функции должен присутствовать атрибут seed (прилагаю картинку для примеров обрезки под разные seed):
[image]

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Просто берите x как случайное числ в диапазоне от 0 до ширины картинки минус ширина фрагмента. Тоже  самое для y от 0 до высота картинки минус высота фрагмента(кадра).  далее crop=img[y:height+y, x:width+x, :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, нашел верхний левый угол таким образом:

```
y = np.random.randint(img.shape[1]-height)
x = np.random.randint(img.shape[0]-width)
```

А чтобы найти конечную точку(нижнюю правую) для обрезки изображения просто прибавил к найденным точкам x и y требуемые размеры. Кажется все очень просто и логично когда уже заешь и понял решение.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
    def random_crop(img, width=None, height=None, seed=1):
        np.random.seed(seed)
        x = np.random.randint(img.shape[1]-height)
        y = np.random.randint(img.shape[0]-width)
        crop = img[y:height+y, x:width+x]
        plt.axis("off")
        return crop
    plt.imshow(random_crop(img_cv,width=100,height=100,seed=3))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]